# Sweatpants and basketball shorts in the nine days

Tags: halacha, clothing, nine-days, sport-athletics

During the nine days, people do not wear freshly laundered clothing as a sign of mourning for the destruction of the Temples. This applies to shirts, pants, coats etc (all examples of regular clothing), but not to underclothes<sup>1</sup> ([*Laws of the Three Weeks*](http://artscroll.com/Authors/Rabbi_Simcha_Bunim_Cohen.html), Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen, page 85).

What are not mentioned in either group (unless I missed it) are clothes meant for exercise, for sweating in, such as basketball shorts or sweatpants. What is the status of clothes such as basketball shorts with regard to the laws of the nine days?

Does it make a difference if the clothes are being worn to exercise ("sweat") in, or if they're worn just for relaxation?

---

<sup>1</sup> *Rabbi Cohen does write (there) that some are מחמיר even on underclothes, but for the purposes of this question we'll assume that you don't have to.*

Comment: How about socks? I hope they're included. Otherwise, I better bring loads of antifungal and deoderant sprays along with a giant bag of clothespins for my nose.

Comment: @DanF IIRC socks go with underclothes.

Comment: I can see a difference between  undergarments which many ppl change daily while sweatpants are not

Comment: Another perhaps related question is the classification of pajamas.

Comment: @andrew Pajamas are disussed there -- the go with underclothes, which some say need to prepare but most say not.

Comment: I have heard in the name if Reb  Moshe Feinstein that dress shirts are also allowed to be worn fresh. They are under the generalization of bigdei ze'ah as the collars get sullied with sweat.

Comment: @user6591 that's a big chiddush since that's not it's functions,also I think the olam would know this b Shem Rav Moshe

Comment: @sam it is. And now they do:) the information came from one if his  Tendler grandchildren. It is up to anyone's discretion whether to treat that as a credible source or not. All that aside, form and function are not so clear cut from a historical perspective of how these clothes developed.

Comment: @user6591 So it's not something I could show someone inside? That's a shame....

Comment: @Shokhet I'm not sure. This grandson was supposedly getting ready to print a book of things he heard from reb Moshe, and his different minhagim. I'm not sure if he ever did. He might have pamphlet versions somewhere.

Comment: @user6591 are you sure it was Rav Moshe,I see that Rav Abadi held like this

Comment: @sam that was what I was told. It was one of my friends who spoke to R' Tendler who related this in the name of his grandfather. I can't verify anything beyond that.

Answer (score 4):

The halachic category allowed to be worn laundered is *beged ze'ah* -- literally, "sweat clothes." Rabbi Cohen gave the example of undergarments, but a simple translation of the term would give you every indication that athletic clothing that gets truly sweaty would in fact be "sweat clothes."

To second user6591's comment above, I have also heard an oral tradition in the name of Rabbi Moshe Feinstein that a button-down shirt gets sufficiently sweaty by the end of the day (if you live in New York in July/August) to also qualify as *beged zeah.*

UPDATE: *Mesoras Moshe* quotes Rabbi Feinstein telling Rabbi Shimon Eider that if a businessman forgot to pre-wear shirts before the Nine Days, he may wear laundered (but not brand-new) shirts as necessary for meetings, "but it's not a nice thing." That's much less of a leniency than the oral shirts-are-sweatclothes argument. (I'm not doubting it, just noting it's not textually supported in this particular work.)